# Can we run AVX required software without, having it?

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, dockerfile

My CPU don't have AVX support, is there any possible way where I can run this. Any online platform, dependencies, etc...

```sh
❯ sudo docker run -d \
-p 27017:27017 \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
--name mongodb \
--net mongo-network \
mongo
8ee99e01dfdea26fd50049d411a99c70c6663db7fffb5cbd4e10d6550fefab19
❯ sudo docker logs 8ee99e01dfdea26fd50049d411a99c70c6663db7fffb5cbd4e10d6550fefab19

WARNING: MongoDB 5.0+ requires a CPU with AVX support, and your current system does not appear to have that!
  see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-54407
  see also https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-5-0-cpu-intel-g4650-compatibility/116610/2
  see also https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/485#issuecomment-891991814

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 412:    29 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}" --fork
```

btw, thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you check the three URLs given to see if they have any useful information?

Comment: Can it be done _at all_? If you use a CPU emulator (not a virtualization tool, but an emulator), yes; but it's incredibly slow, and increases the RAM requirements hugely, so you'd be better off getting a machine with a modern CPU -- AVX has been around for years, it's available even in junk computers people are throwing away now.

Comment: To clarify (just in case that Docker GitHub link ever breaks), MongoDB 5.0+ needs either an Intel Sandy Bridge or later or AMD Bulldozer or later. CPUs older than that can't get around the AVX requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just helped to fix similar problem on M1 Mac to a colleague, we managed to resolve it by defining platform along with the image name. We used:

image: arm64v8/mongo:5.0
platform: linux/arm64/v8

so in the command it is:

```
docker run --platform linux/arm64/v8 ...
```

and in the docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  mongodb:
    image: arm64v8/mongo:5.0
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
```

In our case it works at the end also without the `--platform`, only with changing the image name from `mongo` to `arm64v8/mongo`.

Comment: WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error

Comment: would be nice if you add some useful info, not only complain that you got error, for Mac it worked, if you have something else, tell us so that people know what is the issue background